# alembic "failed to create process." in Windows7

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I already installed python2.7, pip, env and alembic successfully,

I try to run command "alembic init elembic" in command prompt but it not success, it show the message "failed to create process.".

Anyone why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably seeing this as a result of a [pip bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2783) where it fails to correctly quote the python install path if it includes any spaces.

You can work around it by either installing python to a path without any spaces or editing the first line of scripts generated by pip in the \Scripts directory. The generated first line looks something like:

```
#!c:\program files\python 2.7\python.exe
```

and needs to have quotes added around the path like this:

```
#!"c:\program files\python 2.7\python.exe"
```