# failed to create process when running conda in anaconda

Tags: anaconda

I have installed anaconda, I am not able to find anaconda navigator, so I tried to open it by command prompt. But when I fire conda command it says failed to create process. My path doesn't have spaces and I have tried reinstalling it nothing seems to be worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152589/anaconda-failed-to-create-process

Comment: I have tried that solution nothing seems to be work I have mentioned, I have tried some solutions